# Etching PCB - dealing with anhydrous ferric chloride

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I'm looking into PCB etching,which requires ferric chloride (There are other etchants, but they're pretty hard to come by where I live and too expensive if I can find them).

The issue is that where I live, only anhydrous ferric chloride is sold (Which is stupid. They don't even label it properly as anhydrous - got exposed to HCl fumes for 2-3 hours, thankfully the doctor found nothing abnormal with me and I got sent off with some anti allergy meds).

I'd like to know what equipment I'll need to deal with this stuff safely. I always use nitrile gloves with these, but in particular what kind of respiratory protection will I need? I plan on just having 4 PC fans blow these fumes outside the window. If I must, I will invest in respiratory protection (It's very expensive where I live, the NIOSH approved ones at least). I'm assuming a 3M 6002 will be enough.
Please keep in mind I will be using this stuff at home. If you have any suggestions regarding alternatives, do mention them. If I can find it, I'd rather use that than this.
If this isn't the proper place to ask these questions, please direct me to a place more suitable for these questions.

Answer (score 1):

$\ce{FeCl3}$ ( and similarly $\ce{AlCl3}$ ) has very different properties, comparing its anhydrous and hydrate form. They cannot be easily transformed one to the other. Heated hydrate decompose to the oxychloride or oxide eventually. Anhydrate put in water undergoes violant hydrolysis.

I suggest obtaining the hydrate, or preparing it yourself, e.g. reacting of iron, $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{H2O2}$ ( this mixture of the 2 reagens was an alternative Cu etching solution, when $\ce{FeCl3}$ hydrate was not easily available in the communist Czechoslovakia, but is more aggressive then $\ce{FeCl3(aq)}$ ).

Another option is to let react the anhydrate with limited water outdoors and that adding concentrated HCl. For the dissolving itself it would be the best to put in directly to the acid:water 1:1, but it would develop dangerous fumes.

Avoid mixing concentrated stuff, it would turn into a chlorine chemical weapon. Start with 10% peroxide and 1:1 acid, calculate the ratio. Tune it later at will. Keep the etching solution rather mild than strong, to simulate etching performance of FeCl3. My experience with etching $\ce{Cu}$ circuit boards was that too strong solution was often etching metal under the protection layer. Be aware of proper after treatment, to prevent future corrosion.

Usual gloves, coat and eventually shield. Well vented place is needed, at least for first experiments, until you know the behaviour ( I mean rather passively - like outdoor - and just temporary for initial experiments. when it is settled, it is not much needed. ).

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of PPE will be required for HCl and H2O2? I've seen it used. Unfortunately I don't have access to HCl, but I do have access to tile cleaning acid, if that works.

Comment: You say well ventilated, how well ventilated? Again, I'm using this stuff at home, the best I can do is use a bunch of PC fans and blow it out a window. I can't afford a fume hood of any sorts as a student.

Comment: Another thing I'd like to clarify - while I was using anhydrous FeCl3 (The brown-green powder is anhydrous, I'm assuming), the first couple of PCBs did etch just fine. Why is that so if anhydrous FeCl3 is unsuitable for etching?

Comment: Did you perform stoichiometric estimation  ?

Comment: No, I just followed a guide I found online - add the powder to water till dark brown and then etch PCBs. That was about it.

Comment: Typical thickness of Cu is [reportedly](https://www.pcbuniverse.com/pcbu-tech-tips.php?a=4) 1 ounce per square feet of PCB. 1 oz is then about 0.5 mole of Cu, what requires  1 mole of FeCl3, what is about 160 g FeCl3(aq).

Comment: Yup, all copper clad boards will have 1 or 2oz per square feet. It's the standard in most cases. Why does that matter?

Comment: So you need 160-320 g FeCl3 per sq ft of etched out copper. Of course , less, as you need to keep some. So a half of it as a guess. OTHO, you cannot count with 100% performance, as it get slow in the end. So the initial numbers may be applicable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115426/discussion-between-poutnik-and-shahe-ansar).

Comment: That seems about right. But my question was regarding the efficacy of anhydrous ferric chloride. Is my assumption that the brown green powder is anhydrous wrong?

Comment: What is the reason you look for anhydrous stuff if the recipe calls for water?

Comment: @Alchimista I didn't try to look for it, it's all that's available here in India. The recipes I find just say "FeCl3 powder", and the powder in those recipes tend to have a dark brown-green color, so I'm assuming it's anhydrous.

Comment: @Poutnik It's supposedly available as a yellow powder according to what I've read.

Comment: Yes, you are right - it is [yellow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_chloride#/media/File:Iron(III)_chloride_hexahydrate.jpg)

Comment: @ShaheAnsar ok you will be fine with the more yellow one.. It is just that you find the more or less anhydrous form.

Comment: @Alchimista I really wish I could find the solution or the hydrate, but it's pretty rare to come across where I live.

Comment: One final question - regarding the solution I've already made (Regular tap water with anh. FeCl3 added to it), are there any decomposition issues I need to be aware of? I've heard this stuff can give chlorine gas off and I have my previous mixed batch in an airtight plastic container (4-7 days old). At this point I've chosen to switch to sodium persulphate, and am just looking to dispose this stuff off.